# xml data enclosed within tag instead of outside

Tags: xml, tags

This is a very basic question, but I could not find the answer via search, probably I am not using the correct terms, hence asking if you could help.

What exactly is the meaning of the following xml data

```
<OrgName ID="xyz">Apple<OrgName>
```

---> What is the meaning of the data value given within the tag - i.e the ID field? Is it valid for extraction or is it given just for information purposes for the person reading the xml?

Should it be considered similar to:

```
<Org>
<ID>xyz<ID>
<name>Apple<name>
<Org>
```

Comment: That is the standard [XML data-model](https://www.w3.org/XML/Datamodel.html), it is all for extraction per the XML itself. The _meaning_ of the document attributes and values varies for each _use case_ which you have not shared in your question despite asked about.

Comment: If you're asking because you make your mind about your own format, maybe the https://google.github.io/styleguide/xmlstyle.html is a good resource to make up ones mind, it might also be interesting in context of your question more generally.